# How do I publish a npm package for testing?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Is there a way to publish an npm package with a prerelease version, so that I can use it specifically for testing and not affect other users who run `npm install <package-name>`?

I've tried setting the version to v1.0.0-0 and publishing it, I want users to continue pulling v1.0.0 from npm, but even setting such a prerelease version overrides the latest package and users will pull v1.0.0 when they run `npm install <package-name>`.

I do know about `npm link`, but I wish to test how does npm install the dependencies in my project to avoid publishing broken code.

Comment: [`nmp-version`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version) appears to take care of that.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not the ideal solution but what about publishing a major version like `2.0.0` and make sure users use `^1.0.0` in their `package.json` so that when they pull they don't pull in `2.0.0` since it's a major release change. Once you are ready to publish real changes, push to say `1.2.0` and then `unpublish` 2.0.0

EDIT: I talked the npm people today and the way to do it is to use tags

`npm publish --tag alpha`

by default npm publish as `latest`, and that's the one users get when they pull. you can also ask your users to pull `alpha` to test alpha release